# How to swap keys <-> values without try/except and without hash function?

Tags: python, dictionary, hash, swap

I'm trying to swap and to check if a value is hashable but without using the `hash` function or `try/except` statement.

I tried some codes from google but they are not efficient. I found many codes which implements the `hash` function, but for each type of value there was another code.

```
def hashable(inputt, unhashable):
    try:
        hash(inputt)
    except TypeError:
        print("Not possible!")
        unhashable['unhashable'] = True
        return False
    return True



if __name__=="__main__":
    inputt = {'a': (1, 2, [3])}
    print ("Input:",inputt)
    value=0
    key=0
    unhashable = {'unhashable': False}
    output={value:key
            for key, value in inputt.items()
            if hashable(value, unhashable)}
    if not unhashable['unhashable']:
        print ("Output:", output)
```

If the

```
inputt={'a': 123, 'b': 456}
```

The output should be

```
Output: {123: 'a', 456: 'b'}
```

And also if the

```
inputt={'a': (1, 2, [3])}
```

The output should be

```
Output: Swap is not possible
```

Comment: why do you want that? you'll have to recursively check that all data in your structure is hashable... not easy

Comment: I want to do that because im laerning python and that's the phase where i'm at.

Comment: You'd need an exhaustive list of hashable types if you want to do it without try/except and/or `hash`

Comment: if you have new keys (old values) collision then you can use `defaultdict(list)` to keep conflicting values as list and to perform linear search on them.